# Returning from dismiss modal view controller - any way to detect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Wonder if anyone can help me. I have a setup whereby a main menu presents the main game as a modal view controller. At this point it also stops playing the main menu music.

The problem is that when the game view controller dismisses itself (e.g when user quits game) and returns to the main menu I cannot get the main menu music to start playing again.

Is there some way I can get the music in the main menu to start playing again ? E.g a delegate method that is called when the main game dismisses ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the NotificationManager

```
// set up notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playMusic:) 
                                         name:@"musicNotification"
                                         object:nil];

// send notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"musicNotification"
                                         object:self];
// clean up notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[super dealloc];

- (void) playMusic:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // play the music here
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"musicNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Received musicNotification!");
}
```